# HTML Text with Time Limit

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering how I would be able to have some text show up for a few seconds in html? I want to have a loading sign in my website to show up for 10 seconds, then go away. How could I go about doing that? I don't use HTML that often.

**Code I want to add Loading and flash to.**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<title>Catalog</title>

</head>

<body>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="590" id="AutoNumber1" height="32">
    <tr>
        <td width="320" height="77" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <p align="center">      <img border="0" src="images/logoblue.gif" width="307" height="61"></td>
<td width="380" height="77">
        <p align="center"><b><font size="5">PRODUCTS, INC.<br>
</font></b><font size="4"></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="590" height="10" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" colspan="2">
        <img border="0" src="images/divid1.gif" width="700" height="10"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000" id="obj1" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" border="0" width="842" height="539">
    <param name="movie" value="catalog.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="High">
    <embed src="catalog.swf" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="obj1" width="842" height="539"></object>
</p>

</body></html>
```

**Updated code with Virendra's changes:**

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<title>Catalog</title>
 <style type='text/css'>
    #swf_file{display:none;}
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
var timePeriodInMs = 20000;

setTimeout(function() 
{ 
    document.getElementById("texttohide").style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById("swf_file").style.display = "block"; 
}, 
timePeriodInMs);
</script>
</head>

<body>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="590" id="AutoNumber1" height="32">
    <tr>
        <td width="320" height="77" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <p align="center">      <img border="0" src="images/logoblue.gif" width="307" height="61"></td>
<td width="380" height="77">
        <p align="center"><b><font size="5">PRODUCTS, INC.<br>
</font></b><font size="4"></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="590" height="10" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" colspan="2">
        <img border="0" src="images/divid1.gif" width="700" height="10"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="texttohide">
    <img border="0" src="loading.gif" width="144" height="138"></div> 
<div id="swf_file"><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000" id="obj1" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" border="0" width="842" height="539">
    <param name="movie" value="catalog.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="High">
    <embed src="catalog.swf" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="obj1" width="842" height="539"></object>
</div>

<p>
</p>

</body></html>
```

**Update of an Update**

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<title>Catalog</title>
 <style type='text/css'>
    #swf_file{display:none;}
    #swf_file{height:1px; width:1px;}
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
var timePeriodInMs = 10000;

setTimeout(function() 
{ 
    document.getElementById("texttohide").style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById("swf_file").style.height = "138px"; 
    document.getElementById("swf_file").style.width = "144px"; }, 
timePeriodInMs);
</script>
</head>

<body>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="590" id="AutoNumber1" height="32">
    <tr>
        <td width="320" height="77" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <p align="center">      <img border="0" src="images/logoblue.gif" width="307" height="61"></td>
<td width="380" height="77">
        <p align="center"><b><font size="5">PRODUCTS, INC.<br>
</font></b><font size="4"></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="590" height="10" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" colspan="2">
        <img border="0" src="images/divid1.gif" width="700" height="10"></td>
    </tr>
</table> 

<div id="texttohide">
    <b><font size="5">Loading for a few seconds...</font></b></div> 
<div id="swf_file">
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000" id="obj1" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" border="0" width="879" height="564">
    <param name="movie" value="catalog.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="High">
    <embed src="catalog.swf" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="obj1" width="879" height="564"></object>
</div>

<p>
</p>

</body></html>
```

Comment: you will have to use JavaScript/jQuery for this.

Comment: Why would you want something to show loading for a constant 10 seconds rather than waiting until it has actually loaded?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to use some obscure CSS hack to do something like this.

Comment: I am trying to show a flash slideshow, I am not sure how to have it show a loading sign until it finishes loading, so I would rather put a set time. Could someone please give me sample code? That would be great. Thanks

Comment: @icktoofay: I smell a fake loading icon...kinda tacky.

Comment: How are you loading the flash slideshow? I am not sure, but there might be a way to show loading image until the slideshow is loaded.

Comment: I am just putting the flash slideshow in the page, but for a person that first goes to the site, it would take a few seconds to load it, so I wanted to have a loading sign until it is done loading

Comment: I highly suggest _against_ having a set time. 10 seconds is a *very* long time. No one is gonna wait that long. Also, why are you using flash for a simple slideshow? Throw in jQuery and a slideshow plugin. Then you can have a loader _that works_ and code that you can update and maintain yourself and will work in all browsers since you said you need it to be cross browser compatible.

Comment: Also, loading will probably be faster just using jQuery rather than having to load up Flash. Flash is dead, let's keep it that way ;)

Comment: Never even heard of JQuery until now. I usually just do Android programming. Let me look into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/KyC3N/

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Hide Text demo</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#texttohide').delay(5000).fadeOut();
      });
    </script>
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div id="texttohide"> Text to hide in 5 seconds </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

**Update**:  as per updated requirements.
This fiddle uses only JavaScript. It will display a div for 5 seconds and then hide it and display another div.
http://jsfiddle.net/xZEvb/

Here is the complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type='text/css'>
    #swf_file{display:none;}
  </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var timePeriodInMs = 5000;

setTimeout(function() 
{ 
    document.getElementById("texttohide").style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById("swf_file").style.display = "block"; 
}, 
timePeriodInMs);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="texttohide"> Text to hide in 5 seconds </div> 
    <div id="swf_file">This is swf file</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask for jQuery.

Comment: @jfriend00 - The OP seems not to have that much experience with HTML and this is why he probably did not ask for js... Beside, I never heard of the `<show_10_seconds>` tag in HTML... :o

Comment: That's why I provided an answer using regular javascript, not jQuery.  The general rule here on SO is that you don't offer an answer using jQuery unless the OP asks for jQuery or tags it with jQuery.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot, but let me try the JavaScript one too.

Comment: I wonder if the OP knows that using your code, they just added 245kb to their page for a simple disappearing message when it could have been done in less than 1k.  If jQuery is being used for lots of things (general web framework), it may be worth it, but it's kind of silly to  add this much fat to a page for one feature.

Comment: Also, jfriend00, while you are here, can I ask if you know how to have it hide the swf file for like 5 seconds, but load it, then after 5 seconds, show the swf file? If you could help me with that, I wouldn't know how to repay you! Thanks :)

Comment: @AubtinSamai I have updated my answer as per your new requirements. This solution is using HTML, CSS and Javascript (no jQuery).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am trying your example, but I have never used CSS before, so I was wondering if you could put the code together for me, I will update my code with the code I currently have, not including what you just gave me. Thanks a lot. I am probably bothering you with this. :(

Comment: I have updated my answer to add my complete code. To add CSS for my answer you have to just use the `<style type='text/css'>#swf_file{display:none;}</style>` as shown.

Comment: Thanks, it works!!!! Just a question, while it would show the text that will go away in the 5 seconds, does it load the flash slideshow?

Comment: Yes it should. The CSS code is just hiding the div but the content should still be loading inside it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6255/discussion-between-aubtin-samai-and-virendra)

Comment: Well, it seems like it works fast in Internet Explorer 9, but it does not do the job in Google Chrome. In Internet Explorer, it does what you said, loads in background. In Google Chrome, it shows the loading icon, then it loads the flash slideshow.

Comment: Adobe flash is often tuned to NOT load things when not visible in order to save resources for things that aren't going to be shown.  The common workaround is to make the flash object 1x1 pixel and then make it larger when you want it to be shown.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: In css do this `#swf_file{height:1px; width:1px;}` and in JavaScript code change `document.getElementById("swf_file").style.display = "block"; ` to `document.getElementById("swf_file").style.height = "138px"; document.getElementById("swf_file").style.width = "144px"; `

Comment: I added those, it doesn't show up. I will add the code as "Update of an Update" Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this with plain javascript and HTML since you didn't ask for a solution using any frameworks like jQuery or YUI:

```
<div id="tempMessage" style="display: none;">This is my message</div>

function showMessage(text, time) {
    var o = document.getElementById("tempMessage");
    o.style.display = "block";
    o.innerHTML = text;
    setTimeout(function() {
         o.style.display = "none";
    }, time);
}
```

The time value is a number of milliseconds that you want the message to display for.  The text can be any HTML.  The message will display in the place that you put the message HTML in your page.

Sample implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ePxLB/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without Javascript using CSS3 `animation` and `@keyframes`. `position: absolute;` will prevent the splash from affecting any layout and the `height: 0` animation gets it out of the way when finished.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/SwV9m/

CSS:

```css
#splash {
    animation:             splash 3s linear; /* 3s for 3 seconds */
        -moz-animation:    splash 3s linear; 
        -webkit-animation: splash 3s linear; 
            -ms-animation: splash 3s linear; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes splash { 
    0% {opacity:0; height: 100px;} 
    15% {opacity:1;} 
    85% {opacity:1;} 
    99% {opacity:0; height: 100px;}
    100% {height: 0px;} }
@-moz-keyframes splash { 
    0% {opacity:0; height: 100px;} 
    15% {opacity:1;} 
    85% {opacity:1;} 
    99% {opacity:0; height: 100px;}
    100% {height: 0px;} }
@-webkit-keyframes splash { 
    0% {opacity:0; height: 100px;} 
    15% {opacity:1;} 
    85% {opacity:1;} 
    99% {opacity:0; height: 100px;}
    100% {height: 0px;} }
@-ms-keyframes splash { 
    0% {opacity:0; height: 100px;} 
    15% {opacity:1;} 
    85% {opacity:1;} 
    99% {opacity:0; height: 100px;}
    100% {height: 0px;} }
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="splash">3 second splash!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I need a standard solution, and as you said, it is not supported by Internet Explorer 9 yet, so I could not probably use that. Thanks though.